# Собственный словарь

Tags: словари

Мне поручено написать грубо говоря словарь на другом(выдуманном) языке к одной расе. Всё, в принципе, на бумаге есть(около 1000 слов) и даже большая часть записана отдельно на звук.

Нужно перенести **словарь** в электронный вид , причем сделать так, что бы можно было бы **сортировать** по *алфавиту* , по *типу слова* (существительное,глагол), *виды числительных* и т.д. что бы было *(слово на русском)*-*(транскрипция)*-*(слово на языке)*-*(кнопка произведения записи слова)*.

Причем, что бы можно было бы **вводить целое предложение** (именно теми словами,как оно записано изначально*(если например глагол в неопределенной форме, то и предложение в запросе будет немного коверкано соответственно)*внутренний поисковик то бишь) и получать перевод, а так же последовательную смесь звуковой дорожки.
Как бы в виде некоей таблицы, но в отдельном окне, что бы запускалось без доп. программы(желательно),
В принципе была идея прописать вручную через **Basic** или *html*.

**Вопрос такой** : может ли кто посоветовать программу, где было бы проще это реализовать? Или лучше написать вручную, через basic?

Comment: на языке говорить можно?))или только отдельные слова?)

Целое предложение вы с падежами хотите переводить?т.е. осмысленное предложение а не набор слов?Это вам не 1 вечер сидеть на бэйсике

Comment: Это ничего страшного, времени дано очень много.
Говорить можно в принципе.
Целое предложение желательно с падежами, но вообще можно и так, главное что бы не по одному слову искать))
То есть лучше на бейсике?